# Remove XML declaration using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have below XML and want to remove the xml declaration from the payload using XSLT.Please suggest.
Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<1>
<a>test1</a>
<a>test2</a>
</1>
```

Output:

```
<1>
<a>test1</a>
<a>test2</a>
</1>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use the `xsl:output` tag

```
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

With the identity transform

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If I use above I get the content and not the complete nodeset.<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: you're looking for the identity transform as well